# Golang multipart.Reader Not detecting boundary

Tags: xml, go, http, hikvision, mimemultipart

I am working on a project, where I need to get the events from a hikvision camera. Using the */ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream* endpoint. Which uses multipart/mixed over HTTP server push.

The issue I am having is when I try to io.ReadAll() or io.Copy() and the program just gets stuck. In wireshark I can see the stream of XML events coming in. So I tried scanner see below code. and print out line by line which it does including the *--boundary*. Which suggest the multipart Reader fails to detect the boundary. Thus the *readPartData()* never returns.

```
parser := multipart.NewReader(resp.Body, bod)

        for {
            log.Println("New Part")
            part, err := parser.NextPart()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("NextRawPart:", err)
                continue
            }

            da, err := readPartData(part)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                continue
            }

            log.Println(da)

            part.Close()
        }
```

```
func readPartData(part *multipart.Part) (string, error) {
    var buffer []byte
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(part)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Bytes()
        fmt.Println(string(line))
        buffer = append(buffer, line...)
        buffer = append(buffer, '\n')
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    partData := string(buffer)
    return partData, nil
}
```

Multipart stream

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 468

<EventNotificationAlert version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
<channelID>0</channelID>
<dateTime>2023-09-07T10:10:15+10:00</dateTime>
<activePostCount>0</activePostCount>
<eventType>videoloss</eventType>
<eventState>inactive</eventState>
<eventDescription>videoloss alarm</eventDescription>
</EventNotificationAlert>
--boundary
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 468

<EventNotificationAlert version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
<channelID>0</channelID>
<dateTime>2023-09-07T10:10:24+10:00</dateTime>
<activePostCount>0</activePostCount>
<eventType>videoloss</eventType>
<eventState>inactive</eventState>
<eventDescription>videoloss alarm</eventDescription>
</EventNotificationAlert>
--boundary
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 468

<EventNotificationAlert version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
<channelID>0</channelID>
<dateTime>2023-09-07T10:10:34+10:00</dateTime>
<activePostCount>0</activePostCount>
<eventType>videoloss</eventType>
<eventState>inactive</eventState>
<eventDescription>videoloss alarm</eventDescription>
</EventNotificationAlert>
```

Is there something wrong with the boundary hikvision is sending, or am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, **reproducible**, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (and calling `continue` on error is probably part of the issue). [This playground version](https://go.dev/play/p/RyK4UtqOxWr) may help.

Comment: I don't get the log message before continue, so it is never throwing an error. But I just tried and removed and still not. 

The playgroud version works as expected, must be something with the stream of data that I am not seeing.

Comment: Had a quick look at [the docs](https://tpp.hikvision.com/Wiki/ISAPI/Access%20Control%20on%20Person/GUID-C8398309-7417-4540-AF4F-4DA909E766D2.html) and would say that what you are seeing is expected. [This document](http://www.hikvisioneurope.com/za/portal/portal/01-Product%26%20solution%20promotion/02-Solution%20Promotion/03--Solution%20by%20industry%28such%20as%20Mine%2CBank%2Ceducation%2Cetc%29/09-Product%20integration%20technology%20solution/02-Hikvision%20Covert%20Camera%20Integration%20Solution-20190606.pdf) says "it is
not a normal http usage".

Comment: Basically `io.ReadAll()` or `io.Copy()` will read until the connection drops. However this non-standard API keeps the connection open and transmits data as it becomes available.

Comment: Yeah I agree with that. Haha. 
But shouldn't the multipart reader read until the "--boundary" and then pass to io.ReadAll()?
The weird thing is it works on a newer version camera, but for the life of me I can't see any difference from the wireshark log. Other than the newer on has "Connection: close" in the OK header.

Comment: It looks like [multipart](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.1:src/mime/multipart/multipart.go;l=239) scans for a `--boundary` rather than using the `Content-Length` (so if the camera sends the `--boundary` at the start of each message then the issue you are seeing is to be expected).

Comment: Yeah it sends --boundary > Header- > Body. 
So if multipart scans for --boundary, what would cause it to be missing each boundary?

Comment: It depends on the timing; I think you need to modify your question.with deiltails from Wireshark.

Comment: I've measured the length of the last chunk using `echo -n ... | wc -c`, and it's 100 bytes less than advertised in the part's `Content-Length`.

Comment: [This code](https://go.dev/play/p/dtK9WtToZFI) sort of works: in the sense it processes the events as expected. But I don't understand from your text whether the server sends the boundary _immediately_ after each part. If it doesn't, the last "event" will always be effectively "lost" because it will linger until the reader sees the next boundary. If that's exactly the problem you're dealing with, you indeed need to write custom part reading code which would rely on each part's `Content-Length` (but it seems it's broken, too).

Comment: All-in-all, I think I personally need more information to exactly understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned. I removed a couple lines from each event which has sensitive information.
How would I best buffer the data based on the content length? so I can then unmarshal the xml as a whole.

Comment: Just use a two-step process: 1) read the header (using `mime.ReadMIMEHeader`) and get the content length from it, then 2) use any convenient method to read that many bytes–`io.ReadFull` with a slice of enough (preallocated) length or wrapping the underlying stream with `io.LimitReader` should work.

Comment: Just be aware that if you wrap the source stream with a `bufio.Reader`, you _have to_ only operate on the resulting reader ever after–because any read operation on a `bufio.Reader` is free to read (and buffer) more data than that `Read` call actually consumed (handed over to the caller).

Comment: You still did not address another point of my question: do I understand correctly that the server you're dealing with does not _end_ each chunk of data it sends out (which comprises a single "event") with a boundary line? (As otherwise I fail to see any problem at all: just use the approach implemented by my code example, unmodified.)

Comment: …And note that you do not actually need to «unmarshal the xml as a whole»: `encoding/xml` provides the `Decoder` type which is able to decode an XML document from a stream. So you can just–given my example–do `dec := xml.NewDecoder(mr.NextPart()).Decode(&receiverVariable)` and it will work "automagically". [Here's how](https://go.dev/play/p/-CljYIhbxwq).